# Steric hindrance during Hydroboration

Tags: organic-chemistry, erratum, c-x-addition

In response to this diagram (Organic Chemistry By David Klein 3rd Edition Page 364):

[image]

The textbook stated

> A comparison of the transition states for hydroboration via
>   Markovnikov addition or anti-Markovnikov addition. The latter
>   will be lower in energy because of decreased steric crowding.

Is it supposed to mean 'former', as the diagram obviously shows higher crowding in the latter transition state?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This would also be more helpful to future readers if you were to cite the textbook and a page number

Comment: @orthocresol Done

Comment: I would argue that bond polarity has more to do with it. In Markovnikov's studies, he dealt with HX addition where H was always more positive than X. In the B-H bond, boron is more positive than H. Thus, I would classify the lefthand TS as Markovnikov-type addition. After the alkylborane oxidation, where O replaces B, the net result is anti-Markovnikov addition of water.